# OpenLens connecting to (an existing) Prometheus

Tags: kubernetes

After installing OpenLens v6.5.2, I saw no performance dashboard. So, I tried to connect the app to the running Prometheus. At home I run Kubernets with Docker Desktop.

In many tutorials I see a 'bundled prometheus' option, but that is not available in the settings I see. Yup, I read about changes since v6.3.

[image]

There is no 'extensions' list. I can reach it via the hamburger menu > File > Extentions. Then the 'Lens metrics' are not selectable.

How can I connect to an existing Prometheus stack? The stack was installed with helm:

```
$ helm repo add prometheus-community https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts
$ helm repo update
$ helm install prometheus prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack --namespace kubernetes-monitoring
```

After installing the prometheus stuff, I see the following CRD's:

```
$ kubectl get crd | grep moni 
alertmanagerconfigs.monitoring.coreos.com 2023-10-08118:02:13Z 
alertmanagers.monitoring.coreos.com 2023-10-08118:02:14Z 
podmonitors.monitoring.coreos.com 2023-10-08118:02:14Z 
probes.monitoring.coreos.com 2023-10-08118:02:14Z 
prometheusagents.monitoring.coreos.com 2023-10-08118:02:14Z 
prometheuses.monitoring.coreos.com 2023-10-08118:02:14Z 
prometheusrules.monitoring.coreos.com 2023-10-08118:02:14Z 
scrapeconfigs.monitoring.coreos.com 2023-10-08118:02:14Z 
servicemonitors.monitoring.coreos.com 2023-10-08118:02:14Z 
hanosrulers.monitoring.coreos.com 2023-10-08118:02:15Z
```

Re-installing is also an option.

The second try was to use the 'Prometheus operated' option. The screen looks like:

[image]

I tried the following entry: kubernetes-monitoring/prometheus-operated:9090

These are the services of the 'kubernetes-monitoring' namespace:

[image]

Comment: Do you have the necessary Custom Resource Definitions (CRDs) for Prometheus correctly set up in your Kubernetes cluster? The key CRDs typically used include Prometheus, ServiceMonitor, and PodMonitor, which help in defining and configuring the Prometheus setup.

Comment: Sure, but why pictures? Why not text, for me to copy-paste from it?

Comment: After the HELM commands (in the question) I posted the list of CRD's. Looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me this helped:
https://github.com/lensapp/lens/issues/840#issuecomment-980806443

Adding these labels to the `prometheus` service (the one exposing port 9090):

```
    operated-prometheus: "true"
    self-monitor: "true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a full cluster address for prometheus service as the "Prometheus service address":

```yaml
SERVICE_NAME.NAMESPACE.SVC.CLUSTER_DOMAIN
```

probably something like this (check the service name and cluster domain)

```yaml
prometheus-operated.kubernetes-monitoring.svc.cluster.local
```

Comment: Alas, does not work.